2D drag and drop dynamic rigid body spinning out of control in Unity
I'm trying to make a 2d game that involves simulating dragging and dropping certain dynamic physics objects (like squares) and I am a beginner. I need it to look like the rest of the object holds a weight when you click on the object at a point. (like a ragdoll, but without any joints) This means that the object holds a center of mass that will kind of swing along the point on it you have clicked as a fulcrum.
So far I have made a rigid body object that can have its center follow my cursor and that holds a center of mass defined by another game object which only seemed to be effective when I let go of the object. I looked around on the web and I learned about the rigid body method AddForceAtPosition, Which I used to keep the 'initial grab point' centered on My cursor as it dragged the rest of the object, with its center of mass around.
However, when I implement this it seems that the object spins and jumps out of control. When I was first making the object follow my cursor, I experienced a similar thing with force overshoot and just added a resistance term which is proportional to velocity and it made the dragging much smoother.
I used two scripts (One for dragging and one for setting the center of mass) on my parent game object (whose children are the sprite and the center of mass) in my attempt to achieve this. Any help with modifying my code or changing the approach would be awesome.
Drag Script (makes a force on an initial grab point follow cursor)
using UnityEngine;
    public class ApplyContinuousForce : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float forceMag = 0.5f; // Force magnitude
        public float resistance = 2f;
        public float maxLaunchVelocity = 10f;
    
        private bool isDragging = false;
        private Vector2 force;
        private Camera mainCamera;
        private Vector3 initialClickOffset;
        private Rigidbody2D rb;
    
        void Start()
        {
            mainCamera = Camera.main;
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
            if (rb == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("No Rigidbody2D component found on this GameObject.");
            }
        }
    
        void OnMouseDown()
        {
            isDragging = true;
            Vector3 mousePosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
            initialClickOffset = transform.position - mousePosition;
            Debug.Log("Mouse Down - Start Dragging");
        }
    
        void OnMouseUp()
        {
            isDragging = false;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxLaunchVelocity);
            Debug.Log("Mouse Up - Stop Dragging. Clamped Velocity: " + rb.velocity);
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            if (isDragging)
            {
                Vector3 currentMousePosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
                Vector2 targetPosition = currentMousePosition + initialClickOffset;
                Vector2 offset = targetPosition - (Vector2)transform.position;
    
                // Calculate the force based on the mouse movement and apply resistance
                force = offset * forceMag - rb.velocity*resistance;
    
                // Apply the force continuously while dragging
                rb.AddForceAtPosition(force, currentMousePosition);
                Debug.Log("Dragging - Force: " + force+" Torque: "+rb.angularVelocity);
            }
        }
    
        private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition()
        {
            Vector3 mousePoint = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePoint.z = 10f; // Set this to the distance from the camera to the object
            return mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePoint);
        }
    }

Change Center of Mass
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeCenterOfMass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform CenterOfMassReference; // The reference transform for the new center of mass
    private Vector2 centerOfMass;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (rb != null && CenterOfMassReference != null)
        {
            // Calculate the new center of mass in local space coordinates
            centerOfMass = transform.InverseTransformPoint(CenterOfMassReference.position);
            // Set the new center of mass
            rb.centerOfMass = centerOfMass;
        }
    }
}

